# App in development hangs every second time it is run

Tags: blackberry-playbook, blackberry-webworks

This is a fairly straightforward question for such odd behaviour, but that is exactly what my app is doing on the Playbook.  I open the app the first time and it runs perfectly.  I close the app, and then open it again and it hangs/freezes after the first action I perform with it.  I then close the app, it seems to reset itself, and then opens and runs perfectly the next time.

I am using the latest WebWorks and am debugging on the PB with a debug token.  My previous app (written/tested on pre OS2.0) worked, and continues to work, just fine.

I am pleased to post code if you would like, but it may be a waste of space.  In an effort to root out the problem, I wrote a quick Hello World app that writes one item to an HTML5 database on the playbook (my main app also uses WebDB), and that app, as simple as it is, has exactly the same behavior.  All my apps function fine in Chrome.

If anyone has any thoughts about what could be causing this behaviour, please post a reply.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0   Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="helloworld.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
<input type="text" id="testDBInput"/>
<button type="button" onclick="testDB()">go</button>
</body>
</html>
```

JavaScript Document:

```
var taskdb=openDatabase ("helloworldDB", "1.0", "test database", 10*1024*1024);

taskdb.transaction(function(tx)
{

tx.executeSql("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS maintable (id integer primary key autoincrement, nametitle TEXT)");

});

function testDB()
{
    var testTitle=document.getElementById("testDBInput").value;
    taskdb.transaction(function(tx)
    {
    tx.executeSql("INSERT INTO maintable (nametitle) VALUES (?)", [testTitle], function (tx, results)
            {
            });
    });

}
```

`blackberry-tablet.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<qnx>
<icon>
 <image></image> 
</icon>
<author>***edited for privacy***</author>
<authorId>***edited for privacy***</authorId>
<platformVersion>1.0.0.0</platformVersion>

</qnx>
```

`config.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<widget xmlns=" http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets"
    xmlns:rim="http://www.blackberry.com/ns/widgets"
    version="1.0.0.0">

  <name>Tester</name>

  <description>
    PB Tester
  </description>

  <rim:orientation mode="landscape"/>
  <rim:loadingScreen  onFirstLaunch="true" >
  </rim:loadingScreen>

  <author>***edited for privacy***</author>
  <icon src="bdicon.png"/>

  <content src="index.html"/>
  <feature id="blackberry.app" required="true" version="1.0.0.0"/>
  <feature id="blackberry.ui.dialog" required="true" version="1.0.0.0"/>

</widget>
```

Comment: I recommend posting your little example. It would probably be useful in its own right beyond debugging this problem.

Comment: @sarnold Fair enought request.  I posted an update, but apparently didn't do a good job of spacing.  It should still be readable.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the javascript crashed when the appli hangs. testDB() has few lines, you can insert alert() to see which line is not reached